# ImportError: cannot import name 'dtensor' from 'tensorflow.compat.v2.experimental'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to create object detection using tensorflow as an assignment.

`ImportError: cannot import name 'dtensor' from 'tensorflow.compat.v2.experimental' (c:\Project\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v2\experimental\__init__.py)`  
I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Don't know much about TF, but maybe the fact that you're using an experimental version could be an origin to the problem

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error. I downgraded to Keras v2.6.0, which fixed the issue.
Hence, as of **16.05.2022**, this seems to be caues by a bug in v2.9.*

To downgrade to v2.6.0, run:

```
!pip install keras==2.6.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try again by upgrading the `TensorFlow` version to the latest version 2.9 and restart the kernel(runtime) to fix this issue.

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.9
#Or
!pip install --quiet --upgrade --pre tensorflow
```

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.experimental import dtensor

print('TensorFlow version:', tf.__version__)

mesh_1d = dtensor.create_mesh([('x', 6)])#, devices=DEVICES)
print(mesh_1d)
```

Output:

```
TensorFlow version: 2.9.1
<tensorflow.dtensor.python.layout.Mesh object at 0x7f890d7ce690>
```

Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/dtensor_overview#setup) link for more details.