# ImportError: cannot import name 'dtensor' from 'tensorflow.compat.v2.experimental' import Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm getting the following error while importing Keras:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'dtensor' from 'tensorflow.compat.v2.experimental' (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v2\experimental\__init__.py)
```

Tensorflow v. 2.6, Keras v. 2.6

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name 'dtensor' from 'tensorflow.compat.v2.experimental'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72177210/importerror-cannot-import-name-dtensor-from-tensorflow-compat-v2-experimenta)

Answer (score 1):

DTensor is part of the TensorFlow 2.9.0 release. To import `dtensor` you can upgrade `tensorflow 2.6` to `tensorflow 2.9` as follows:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.9
```

Now, you can import `dtensor` either from `tensorflow.experimental` or from `tensorflow.keras` as follows:

```
#Using tensorflow.experimental
from tensorflow.experimental import dtensor

#Using tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras import dtensor
```

For more information, please refer to this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/dtensor_overview#setup). Thank you.